# Combined history for vim sp and vsp?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to easily open a file previously opened as a horizontal split as a vertical split in vim? Perhaps some method to combine the history for these commands?

When using vim, I often open multiple files with `:sp` or `:vsp`. Later, when I want to reopen a file previously opened with `:sp` as a vertical split using `:vsp`, the path doesn't exist in the history for `:vsp` so I have to look in the history for `:sp` as well and then change `sp` to `vsp`...

**Use case:**

`:sp ../../some/very/long/annoying/to/type/path/to/a/file.cpp`

`:wq`

... time passes ...

`:vsp <up arrow>` (not found, argh)

`:sp <up arrow>` (found, edit `sp` to `vsp`)

Comment: if you open the split first, then edit, you will have a common history.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I don't understand what you mean. I want to avoid remembering in what way I previously opened a file (be it `sp` or `vsp`) in order to reopen it.

Comment: Hmm, that is a slight improvement.

Answer (score 3):

## You are doing all that in the same session

Buffers created with `:e`, `:sp`, `:vs` and various other commands are listed in the "buffer list". If you want to re-edit one of those buffers in a vertical window the original command used to edit the file doesn't matter. You simply do:

```
:vert sb <Tab>
```

## You are doing that in two different sessions

Vim keeps a list of edited files between sessions. To re-edit a previously edited file in a vertical window, do:

```
:oldfiles
(decide you want the number 15)
:vs#<15
```

Answer (score 2):

This `:autocmd` will add to each `:sp` / `:vsp` command the corresponding `:vsp` / `:sp` command to the command-line history, so that you can recall with any other command:

```
:autocmd! BufWinEnter * if histget(':', -1) =~# '^v\?sp\s' |
\   call histadd(':', substitute(histget(':', -1), '^v\?', '\=empty(submatch(0)) ? "v": ""', '')) |
\   endif
```

#### Alternative

There are several plugins that offer a most-recently opened file list, e.g.

- [MRU Menu - Plugin to manage a MRU](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=207)
- [mru.vim - Plugin to manage Most Recently Used (MRU) files](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=521)
- [FuzzyFinder - buffer/file/command/tag/etc explorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984)

This also offer different mappings to open in (vertical) splits. With this, you avoid the need to decide on the split type before recalling, and you have a separate history just for the files.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to get the same behavior across `:e` as well?

Comment: @ConradMeyer: Yes, but that would mean you insert 3 commands (`:e`, `:sp`, `:vsp`) into the history for each edited file. So that approach doesn't scale too well. Oh, and the simple conditional in my answer would need to be turned into an `if..then..else`, for readability best in a separate function.